# variable reference in a sed expression in a while loop

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I have been working on a KornShell (ksh) script where I am struck with an error with sed expression.
I have a file named abc with 100 entries and I want to assign every 8th argument in every line of abc file to a variable.

I have used something like this.

```
#!/bin/ksh
typeset -i x=1
while read line ; do
    var1=$(sed -n '$xp' abc.txt | awk '{print $8}')
    print $var1
    x="$x+1"
done < abc.txt
exit
```

I want to refer to variable x as the line number, but I am getting an error with sed expression in referencing x variable. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Your quotes are wrong. Anything in single quotes is a verbatim string; if you want variable interpolation, you need to use double quotes (or, in very special circumstances, no quoting at all).

You might as well refactor everyting into Awk, too. Trivially,

```
var1=$(awk -v n="$x" 'NR==n{ print $8 }' abc.txt)
```

However, the main loop reading the whole file again just to get one line out of it is highly inefficient. Maybe you want something like

```
awk '{ print NR, $8 }' abc.txt |
while read x var1; do
    print "$var1"
    # presumably do something with $x too?
done
```